# get the select options from an update form django

Tags: html, django, templates

I am working with django I need to do an update form, I already created the view and the form and everything but still this select options in my template I am stuck in this one.

```
<select name="gender">
            <option value="{{request.user.profile.gender}}">{{request.user.profile.gender}}</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

the user should see his gender and he still can see the other option so he can update his gender, you know what I mean.
the list is really bad now because I have now 3 options and I should have only 2options Male and Female.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of all of this I just put {{profile_form.gender}} without the need of all of this.
in my view I have already this :

```
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateF(instance=request.user.profile)
```

in my form :

```
class ProfileUpdateF(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
       model = Profile
       fields = ['gender',]
```